# Isometric Game Engine for Android

Tags: android

Are there any existing open source or commercial solutions for this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is not a solution (that I know of) aimed only at making isometric games. But isometric games are just tiled games. The main differnce is a few simple math tricks relating to converting x and y game coordinates to x and y screen coordinates. But this math is pretty well documented in a variety of languages.

I learned about it from Actionscript. The syntax of Actioncript is nearly identical to java, so you should be able to follow this tutorial pretty easily:
http://www.tonypa.pri.ee/tbw/tut16.html

And there are at least two engines that I know of that support 2D tile-based games:
Cocos2d for Android and AndEngine.

http://code.google.com/p/cocos2d-android/

http://www.andengine.org/

I believe Unity3D is planning to release a 2D version of their toolkit as well. 
http://unity3d.com
But you could just as well make a 3D game with a fixed camera.

== Update ==
As of March 2012, Adobe flash now has a pretty good export to android and iOS, provided you use the new stage3D feature, and *not* the traditional display list. Fo a 2D tile-based game, a starting point would be using the starling framework for flash.

== Update 2 ==
As of January 2013, Unity now has official support for 2D games. I've tried making games with it and I can highly recommend it.

Comment: This is a great answer actually. Thanks!