# Android 2D graphics game engine?

Tags: android, game-engine

I'm trying to find a good 2D graphics engine for a game... Something for a game like a top-down (slight angle so it looks 3D...) allowing the user to move around.. that sort of game...

Any help would be great, Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you it sounds like you want to make an "isometric" style 2D game. There's [another question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5849782/isometric-game-engine-for-android) that has a good answer as well.

As others have noted, AndEngine might be the way to go.  Apparently it can load tile maps in [Tiled Map Editor format (TMX)](http://www.mapeditor.org/), which offers support for isometric maps.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend [AndEngine](http://www.andengine.org/).

They have an app demonstrating its ability on the market called AndEngineExamples.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.andengine.org/

examples are available and you check out performance etc..  I know there are even some youtube videos specific to andengine

Answer (score 0):

Andengine is great but it's resolutely 2D and you sound like you'd really like to do 3D.

An obvious alternative would be Unity - as it supports Android amongst it's many deployment platforms (and it's free!!)